# How to connect Jira Webhook to Azure service bus

Tags: jira, webhooks, azureservicebus

I am trying to connect the Jira webhooks to Azure Bus services to send my payload from Jira to Azure. When I tried using requestbin, I can able to receive the json payload from Jira webhook. But, when i tried with azure service bus URL in Jira , i am not receiving any messages. The Active message count is zero. Please help me in this case

Answer (score 0):

Service Bus by itself will not push anything anywhere. You may try Service Bus Queue or Event Hub in combination with a Function App. The Function could be created with the trigger template for Queue or Event Hub. The Function could then call your WebHook or do any other things as per your requirement.
Relevant Links :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp
https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples

Or, you can check the [Azure Service Bus to Event Grid integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-to-event-grid-integration-concept)